# Finding all variations of a list of substrings in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

I have a list of strings of movie names which I want to search in a pandas dataframe column `description` and make a new column `movie_name` if it is found in the description entered by a user.

Now, since the descriptions are not standardised, how can I search all the possible variations of a particular name. For eg. one of the movie names is `HARRY POTTER 4`. Now, I need to search all possible inputs like `HARRYPOTTER 4`, `HARRY POTTER4`, `HARRYPOTTER4` etc. There may be cases where user didn't left space after the `4` and typed other stuff for eg. `HARRY POTTER 4is a good movie`.

I need to extract the movie names given in the list from the descriptions and add a new column of just `movie_name`. Is there any other way than adding all the possible variations in the list, using `.contains` and `.extract` and later mapping all of them to 1 final movie name using `.map` or `.replace`?

Comment: Please provide sample dataframe along with what you have tried.

Comment: You'll need textdistance for similar text search rather than exact text search. Take a look at [this](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/)

Comment: @Vishnudev I will look into that. Just to add, can I use regex here in this case? If yes, could anyone guide me how?

Comment: Are you sure that the variation will be just space? If yes, then remove space and then search.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the FuzzyWuzzy library.

Here is an easy to understand article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fuzzywuzzy-python-library/